# apply custom theme in android preference

Tags: android, android-listview, themes, preference

I want to do few things in my preference screen.

1. apply custom font to the title
2. change some icons of preference
3. change background color and font color when the preference is selected(or touched?)

First, I started with CheckBoxPreference.
to apply a custom font, I make myCheckBoxPreference.

```
public class MyCheckBoxPreference extends CheckBoxPreference {
    public String robotoRegular = "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf";

    public MyCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public MyCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCheckBoxPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(), robotoRegular);
        titleView.setTypeface(tf);

        return view;

    }
}
```

and it works fine.

to change the checkbox image, I made a theme and apply it.

in my styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/MyCheckbox</item>
</style>
<style name="MyCheckbox" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/btn_check</item>
</style>
```

to change the background color of preference list, I also made a theme and apply it.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/MyCheckbox</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
</style>

<style name="MyListView" parent="android:Widget.ListView.White">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_background</item>
</style>
```

it works all fine, too.

but I got stucked to change font dynamically. 
I tried using theme

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#717171</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">#dcdcdc</item>    
</style>
```

but not worked.

and I tried using onTouchListener in MyCheckBoxPreference.
now onCreateView in MyCheckBoxPreference.java became as follow

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

    TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(), robotoRegular);
    titleView.setTypeface(tf);
    titleView.setTextColor(0xFF717171);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            TextView titleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            int actionMasked = event.getActionMasked();
            switch (actionMasked)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    titleView.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                {
                    titleView.setTextColor(0xFF717171);
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    Log.d("MyCheckBoxPreference", "action" + event);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

At first, it seemed to work but it has a problem. 
if I touch an item and move my finger to another item, the font color remains white(`0xFFFFFFFF`). 
In that code, the title text color sets first `#717171` in `onCreateView`. When the list item is selected the color changed in onTouch with `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. And I expected when I unselect the item `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` make the font color to `#717171`. However, when I unselect the item, the font color is changed in the `onCreateView`. I think because the preference is changed, the system wants to create the view again.

This works only when preference is toggled. As I mentioned above when I touch an item and move my finger to another item, the font color remains white because preference status remains unchanged and `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` is not reached.

If I return true in OnTouchListener `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` are reached but it consumes the event and background color is not changed.

This is my story to come to here.

I apply styles in ListView by making custom **list_item.xml** and set textColor with my **listview_item_selector.xml** But in the preference, it uses default ListView, so I don't know how to do it.

What should I do? Do I have to customize all the preferences?
Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.